# Pymongo how to properly use $push to update an existing document

Tags: pymongo

I am doing something wrong or I don't understand $push (probably don't understand). Anyway I have the following document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("501c83051d41c8753e000000"), 
  "node" : "denver", 
  "enc" : {
    "environment" : "production",
    "classes" : {
      "denver" : ""
    }
  }, 
  "inherit" : "default"
}
```

And I am trying to make the document

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("501c83051d41c8753e000000"), 
  "node" : "denver", 
  "enc" : {
    "environment" : "production", 
    "classes" : {
      "denver" : "",
      "boulder" : ""
    }
  }, 
  "inherit" : "default"
}
```

This is what my update statement looks like:

```
col.update(
  {
    'node' : 'denver'
  }, 
  {
    '$push': {
      'enc.classes' : {
        'boulder': ''
      }
    }
  },
True)
```

I don't get an error but the document never updates. If I change $push to $set then the denver is replaced with boulder.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This query works.

```
db.foo.update({"node": "denver"}, {"$set": {"enc.classes.boulder": ""}}
```

Comment: It is most excellent to see Boulder used in accepted answers.

Comment: In PyMongo 3.x 'update' has been depreciated. 

You can do the same thing and $push to an array using the following:

    db.foo.update_one({"node": "denver"}, {"$push": {"enc.classes.boulder": ""}}

Answer (score 15):

[`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) does not work in this case because you are trying to use an array function on an object.

To use `$push` you would need to change your data structure to the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("501c83051d41c8753e000000"), 
    "node" : "denver", 
    "enc" : {
        "environment" : "production", 
        "classes" : [
            "denver"
        ]
    }, 
    "inherit" : "default"
}
```

Then your query would be:

```
col.update(
    {
        'node' : 'denver'
    },
    {
        '$push': {
            'enc.classes' : 'boulder'
        }
    },
    True
)
```