# pymongo collection add item using update

Tags: pymongo, ninja

desperately I look for a solution of a very simple problem. I use NINJA and Robomongo as
environment.

I want to add a collection to an existing one, all in the same FOR loop:

existing:

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("54608d9f35121b0e18aa01b2"),
    "level1" : {
        "item1" : 200.55,
        "item2" : "001",
        "item3" : 708874,
     }
  }
```

want to get:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54608d9f35121b0e18aa01b2"),
    "level1" : {
        "item1" : 200.55,
        "item2" : "001",
        "item3" : 708874,
        "level2" : {
            "item4" : 200.55,
            "item5" : "001",
            "item6" : 708874,            
        }

    }
}
```

I tried UPDATE with $set (unset=True), $addToSet etc. Problem seems that it's not an array.

Thanx for help

Answer (score 0):

found the solution in this forum:
[Pymongo how to properly use $push to update an existing document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809663/pymongo-how-to-properly-use-push-to-update-an-existing-document?rq=1)
The first answer was

This query works.

```
db.foo.update({"node": "denver"}, {"$set": {"enc.classes.boulder": ""}}
```

And this works in my case!
Thanx all